# Unable to click on webelement button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Unable to click on webelement button

I tried to click on button by mouse movement but no success

my outer html is as below :

```
<button class="btn btn-alt btn-small" type="button" ng-click="ecdapp.uploadBlueprintModalPopup();"> 
    Create
</button>
```

button xpath is:

`//*[@id="page-content"]/div[3]/button`

Comment: Add part of html code including button you are trying to click, then I'll make clickable xpath for u.

Comment: Outer html code is very huge , unable to paste here . Any other option to paste

Comment: @RohanDoshi: Can you at least include the ancestor elements (the HTML tags that contain this button)?

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing the full page source it's hard to tell where your XPath expression is good or not, you can try locating the button using its [text](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) instead

```
//button[normalize-space(text())='Create']
```

[image]

the [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function is used to discard heading/trailing whitespaces

It might also be the case the button is not immediately available, I would recommend considering using [Explicit Wait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) approach via [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class

```
WebElement myButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space(text())='Create']")));
myButton.click();
```

the above code will try to locate the aforementioned button for 10 seconds and click it as soon as it will be present/visible/clickable. Otherwise it will fail with [NoSuchElementException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html)

Comment: I tried this code , but unable to click . element click intercepted: Element <button class="btn btn-alt btn-small" type="button" ng-click="ecdapp.uploadBlueprintModalPopup();">...</button> is not clickable at point (293, 97). Other element would receive the click: <div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)

Comment: then you need to click the div, not the button. Or this is a form of a modal popup like cookie disclaimer which needs to be dismissed first

Answer (score 0):

May be the Xpath is wrong. Try the below xpath:

//button[contains(text(),'Create')]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the screenshot this Xpath 100% works, if you still won't be able to click on that button, then problem is not with xpath. Let me know if its still fails.

```
 By.xpath("//button[@class = 'btn btn-alt btn-small' and @type = 'button']")
```

[image]

Based on your comment:

*I tried this code , but unable to click . element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (293, 97). Other element would receive the click: ... (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)*

I pretty sure I know whats your problem, before u click on this element, something going on the page:
It says - **Other element would receive the click**, means there is other element above(overlapping) your button(pop up window, page is greyed out(disabled while loading, Some JS running)), so when Selenium trying to click on your button its actually clicking on that blocking element.
Try to click after Thread.Sleep(); wait 5-10 sec.
If this is the case then u need to add condition before find your button to check that element that prevent from clicking on button is disappeared then u click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript executors as below,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath of button>"));
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```